# passing an array as an option to PropTypes.oneOf()

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to pass a selection of values to a certain prop in my code

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
   //... proptypes    
   sortOrder: PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc", ["asc, desc"]]),
}
```

when I pass the option `["asc", "desc"]`

```
<MyComponent sortOrder={["asc", "desc"]} />
```

I get an error

```
Invalid prop `sortOrder` of value `asc,desc` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected one of ["asc","desc",["asc","desc"]].
```

not what I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

ok figured it out, replaced `oneOf` with `oneOfType`

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
sortOrder: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc"]))
```